# how can i troubleshoot problems with import docx

Tags: python, docx

import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- `import docx`
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

I tried typing `import docx`.

Comment: Please share your full code and how your are trying to run it. Are you using any IDE? Which environment, linux/windows ? Any other relevant detail.